# Solution for A/C Condensate Drain Line when it is not possible to drain it elsewhere?

Tags: water, air-conditioning, drain, drainage, condensation

I have a split A/C system in a room that runs on low 24 hours a day during Summer that unfortunately **cannot** be connected to any drain or pipe and which therefore requires a bucket to be used to collect the condensate from the condensate drain line in the exterior unit that sits on my balcony in my apartment building.  **I have not yet been able to solve this issue.**

This is quite frustrating as the bucket has to be emptied every single day (once a day), so I'm looking for a better solution.

Without going into details, connecting the condensation drain line to any drain of any kind, drain line, drainage hole, ground, etc. is **not** an option, so I need an outside-the-box solution.

The bucket is already quite large and gets quite heavy at the end of the day when it's full, so maybe something that makes the water evaporate faster than normal so that I don't have to empty the water so often?

The A/C Condensate Drain Line seems to empty about 3 Gallons / 12 L per 24 hour period.

Potential solutions:

**Humidifier**

- Are there outdoor-friendly humidifiers that could get rid of 3 Gallons/ 12 L per day?  The tank would not have to hold that much as the drain line would just drip the water constantly into the tank.
- CONSIDERATIONS: Would I need to use more than 1 humidifier and serialize them?  Can a humidifier handle being on for 24 hours a day for 4 months straight?  Can a humidifier handle the elements (e.g. could rain affect the circuitry or create any electrical issues)?

**Plant/Grass garden**

- My balcony has 37sqft / 3.4 m2 of area to play with but only 1 hour of direct sunlight (although plenty of indirect sunlight) per day, could I create a garden of plants/grass to absorb the water?
  -CONSIDERATIONS:  How much garden would I need?  Which plants could meet this criteria?  Could the balcony handle the weight of soil + plants + water?

**Any other outside-the-box solutions?**

Would any of the solutions listed above work?  If so, what specific details would I need to make it work?  Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Why can't you let the water drain off the balcony to the ground below?

Comment: @Tester101: Because it is not allowed.  You marked this as a duplicate and there is a notice saying that this question already has answers, but none of those answers from last year actually solved the problem.  So I was more specific with this question this year to hopefully get better answers.

Comment: You could edit the additional detail into the original question. This will bump the question on to the "front page", which will get it more views. Additionally, you could set a bounty on the original question to get more views.

Comment: @Tester101:  I did not realize that editing an old question would get it bumped to the front page, I thought I would just be talking to myself.  I'll go ahead and do that now.  Thank you.

Comment: Adding some photos of the area might help folks think of a solution.

Comment: @Tester101:  I just edited the original question with the new clarifications, potential solutions, and questions, but I don't see it anywhere on the front page, so it doesn't seem to have gotten bumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Refresh your browser, and make sure you're on the "[active](http://diy.stackexchange.com/?tab=active)" questions tab.